# Change client information on invoice odoo 14

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

In the invoice template, i want to change the place of client information, I want the zip code after the street address directly, I can't find the source code of it.
where i can find the source code ?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fount the concatenation fields in `_get_default_address_format(self)` API in `/opt/odoo14/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/res_partner.py`, starting on line 921:

```py
@api.model
def _get_default_address_format(self):
    return "%(street)s\n%(street2)s\n%(zip)s %(city)s  %(state_code)s\n%(country_name)s"
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi I hope this will help you.

1. Open Debug Mode.
2. Go to Settings -> Technical Settings -> Reporting -> Report.
3. Find the name of your print menu.
   [image]

[image]
4. In that menu, you will be able to locate a "Template Name." This will be the main report.
[image]

5. Go to Views and find this template and change as you want

Comment: yes, but i can't find the section that describe contact inforations on invoice.
check the post, I added a picture.

Comment: From this template odoo is calling another template. "report_invoice_document" please check this template you will see the same format which is printing.

Comment: logically, this section should contain client informations, but i can't find in account/view/report_invoice.xml which contain the  "report_invoice_document" .
If you know the real path please help me, i'll be grateful for you.